# Deploying a Flask Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: "ERROR: Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist."

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm struggling to deploy a flask-app to AWS with Elastic Beanstalk. It deploys fine locally but kicks an error when I try to push to EB.

After reading joshmcode's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169260/your-wsgipath-refers-to-a-file-that-does-not-exist), I changed my flask application name from the conventional `app` to `application`, changed my file name to application.py, and made sure the Elastic Beanstalk config file matched. This didn't solve the problem.

**The relevant part of my `eb config` file:**

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
NumProcesses: '1'
NumThreads: '15'
StaticFiles: /static/=static/
WSGIPath: application.py
```

**My File Structure:**

In a folder FlaskAWS, I have the root flask directory ("flask-chatterbot") and the virtual environment, like:

```
venv 
flask-chatterbot
    -requirements.txt
    -application.py
    Templates 
        -index.html
    Static
        css
           -styles.css
        js 
           -dynam.js
```

**Commands before error:**

1. After successfully deploying locally, I froze the package requirements with

   pip freeze > requirements.txt
2. Then deactivted the virtual environment

   deactivate
3. Initialized the CLI repository with the `eb init` command

   eb init -p python example-chatbot

At this point, I choose the version of Python and set up the SSH keys without any problems.

4) After this I ran

```
eb create flask-environ
```

I receive the following error:

```
MacBook-Air:flaskaws patrickharris$ eb create flask-environ
Creating application version archive "app-180409_132356".
Uploading flask-app/app-180409_132356.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: flask-environ
  Application name: flask-app
  Region: us-west-1
  Deployed Version: app-180409_132356
  Environment ID: xxxidxxx
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Python 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.6
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2018-04-09 20:23:59.312000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-1-814752048877 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-0f84dd5f7959f932f
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-19AXML05AP8UG
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-7-AWSEBLoa-5F4QOOSPZA9I
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-1TSKD50BLQBZ7
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UN8HHDRN4V2J
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-1:814752048877:scalingPolicy:f03d20db-305d-4eff-83bd-fa5532d682ea:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UN8HHDRN4V2J:policyName/awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-154NI4YA5Y480
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-1:814752048877:scalingPolicy:f70e6de5-c82d-48f0-9324-db3fd69813a9:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-UN8HHDRN4V2J:policyName/awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-MG1G34PEZK13
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-ELWRG701RZXB
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-7iaptyh9gg-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-FRMTYE8GUX0W
****ERROR: Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.****
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: `WSGIPath: application.py` in eb config, but in your file structure it is `app.py`... get these two file names to match perhaps?

Comment: That was my fault when asking the question, I changed it from app.py to application.py and am still receiving the error. Good look though, thank you.

Comment: how was this issue solved?