# Error while deploying flask app to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk through the console GUI. Following the answer given here [Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169260/your-wsgipath-refers-to-a-file-that-does-not-exist), 
I have named my main file application.py and have set the WSGIPath (through the Beanstalk console GUI) to application.py. Also, I have named my object application, not app. However, I am still getting this error:

> Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.

Here is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

---

Here is the error that shows up

[image]

---

How can I resolve this error?

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169260/your-wsgipath-refers-to-a-file-that-does-not-exist)

Comment: No, I already followed the suggestions given there and am still getting the error